# not filtering my cards on the basis of subcategories

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, strapi

```
import React from "react";
import "./List.scss";
import {Card} from "../Card/Card";
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch";

export const List =({ subCats, maxPrice, sort, catId }) =\> {
const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(
`/products?populate=*&[filters][categories][id]=${catId}${subCats?.map((item) => `&\[filters\]\[sub_categories\]\[id\]\[$eq\]=${item}`)}`
);
return (
  <div className="list">
    {loading
      ? "loading"
      : data?.map((item) => <Card item={item} key={item.id} />)}
  </div>
);
```

};

first it gave me (cannt read properties of undefined reading map) i resolved it by putting question mark to subcats prop. then i cant filter the cards according to the subcategories like if i choose hat only hat should be shown. i can see on console when i choose hat or t-shirt or both it shows in arra but on dom it doesnt remove the card after choosing partcular subcategory

[here is image ][1]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaD1L.png // here is usefetch hook
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMWxA.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3BYU.png // here is makerequest page

Comment: hello, please can you show useFetch hook?